# How to highlight a specific place on Google Maps with Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my Android app, I'm using Google Maps API to display the map of a specific area. In that area there are many places like bars, hotels, restaurants etc as in this

[image: screenshot].

See, in the middle there is place named "Cafe de Ceuvel". My question is, how can highlight somehow that specific location on the map?

Comment: Can't open the picture. Maybe you should upload the screenshot to https://imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set marker with name on specific latitude and longitude.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why to add another marker since that location is already there on the map and it already has a nice marker on it (the one with the cafe)?

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your `MapFragment`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(40.758887, -73.985152))
        .title("Cafe de Ceuvel"))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("image_name",100,100))));
}
```

You have to provide your own resized bitmap to work it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why to add a another marker since that location is already there on the map and it already has a nice marker on it (the one with the cafe)?

Comment: Then how do you want to highlight?

Comment: In any way it is possible but not to add another marker. I don't want to have duplicate markers. Maybe if it's possible to increase the size of the existing one.

Comment: In that way you are adding a circle. I don't want that. I want somehow to use the existing marker. Or to increase the size or change the color. Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible, You should ask the Question like this way that you want to increase the marker size. check update

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to add another marker, as you do in your answer. I want to highlight the existing one. Why to have two markers? See this [image](https://ibb.co/SPzF0dC). There one already there.